# Codeigniter Datatables Library Error

Tags: php, codeigniter, datatables

**I using this library. it's very useful.**

https://github.com/IgnitedDatatables/Ignited-Datatables/blob/master/application/libraries/Datatables.php

```
$this->datatables->select("id, firstname, email, username, register_date, last_login");
$this->datatables->from("User");
$this->datatables->unset_column("id");
$this->datatables->edit_column("firstname", "<span row_id='$1'>$2</span>", "id, firstname");
$nesne = $this->datatables->generate();
```

**error,**

A Database Error Occurred

Error Number: 1096
No tables used
SELECT *
ORDER BY `firstname` asc
LIMIT 10

Filename: /Users/emrecan/Desktop/www/guide/libraries/Datatables.php
Line Number: 261

**i changed from, "User" to "vw_User" before create vw_User view and error,**

A Database Error Occurred

Error Number: 1146
Table 'guide.vw_User' doesn't exist
SELECT `id`, `firstname`, `email`, `username`, `register_date`, `last_login`
FROM (`vw_User`)
ORDER BY `firstname` asc
LIMIT 10
Filename: /Users/emrecan/Desktop/www/guide/libraries/Datatables.php
Line Number: 261

**its right,**

```
CREATE VIEW vw_User AS SELECT * FROM User;
```

**and i have again first error,**

A Database Error Occurred

Error Number: 1096
No tables used
SELECT *
ORDER BY `firstname` asc
LIMIT 10

Filename: /Users/emrecan/Desktop/www/guide/libraries/Datatables.php
Line Number: 261

Comment: Have you tried doing a select on a regular table?  Meaning, are you sure the library supports views?

Comment: view or table doesn't matter. sql is so same for they. and i do not want use this silly view. Problem is library. When i select this table (natural or with view) it's can't generate query.

Answer (score 0):

I used datatables recently... To get it to work, I set everything up in the model and returned the datatables->generate()

The only thing that stands out differently in my setup insofar as datatable code goes is I used the table names in the `SELECT`. It may be important...

```
public function datatable(){  
    include('/www/system/cms/config/database.php');
    require_once('/www/Datatables.php');
    $datatables = new Datatables();
    $config = array(
        'username' => $db['db1']['username'],
        'password' => $db['db1']['password'],
        'database' => $db['db1']['database'],
        'hostname' => $db['db1']['hostname']
            );
    $datatables->connect($config);
    $datatables
    ->select('default_person.name, default_person.work, default_person.id, default_person.place')
    ->from('default_person');
    return $datatables->generate();
 }
```